# Filename extract and insert into column values hive

Tags: shell, hive

I have a file called : `akolp9app1a_170905_0000.txt`

I need to split the values

```
hostname= akolp9app1a

date=170905 (convert into proper data format)
```

Now create a table in hive with 2 columns hostname and date and insert this values into the table.

any suggestion

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use virtual columns, for example **INPUT__FILE__NAME**. It gives the input file's name.

Then you can use **split (or) substring (or) regexp_extract** string functions on the **input__file__name** field and create **hostname,date** values.

**Example:-** 
the below select query gives date field value as 170905, like this way build your query using string functions to extract hostname

```
 hive> select split(INPUT__FILE__NAME,'[\_]')[1] `date` from tablename;
```

Store them to separate table by using insert statement.